# Login to Linux server automatically using SSH key with TeraTerm

Tags: linux, centos

I'm looking for a way to login to Linux server automatically using TeraTerm.
For example, i have an user called tester in CentOS7. 
I created ssh key with ssh-keygen command for tester in his /home/tester/.ssh/ folder. So we have 2 key file here, id_rsa and id_rsa.public

I downloaded id_rsa to my laptop and saved it as tester.pem and used it to login to linux server successfully using Tera Term.
Now i want to make it automatically which means i can just use 1 click to .ttl file and voila, login successful. Here's the script of tester.ttl but it didn't work.

```
username = 'tester'
keyfile = '"C:\path\to\keyfile\tester.pem"' 
hostname = 'server's ip'

pass = '789789'
msg = hostname
strconcat msg ':22 /ssh2 /auth=publickey /user='
strconcat msg username
strconcat msg ' /keyfile='
strconcat msg keyfile

connect msg
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to duplicate your issue. A `login.ttl` file with the following contents allowed me to successfully login to the desired ssh server (after placing the public key in the `authorized_hosts` file on the host).

```
username = 'tester'
hostname = '192.168.100.1'
keyfile = 'c:\path\to\keyfile\id_rsa'

con = hostname
strconcat con ':22 /ssh2 /auth=publickey /user='
strconcat con username
strconcat con ' /keyfile='
strconcat con keyfile
connect con
```

`